# JHipster / Okta Setup Questions

Tags: jhipster, okta

JHipster Generator v4.13.2

I am following Matt Raible's post:

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/10/20/oidc-with-jhipster

Keycloak works fine.

When setting up Okta, I run into issues following the instructions.  Specifically this step:

> Navigate to API > Authorization Servers, click the Authorization Servers tab and edit the default one. Click the Claims tab and Add Claim. Name it “groups” or “roles”, and include it in the ID Token. Set the value type to “Groups” and set the filter to be a Regex of .*.

I can't find this in the Okta Developer portal.  Did I miss it, does the documentation need updated?

Does someone know how to configure this step.

Thanks

Comment: I have an OLD Okta account, ... That appears to be the issue.

Comment: Did you get this fixed? We can enable it via feature flags if you can provide your Okta domain.